# How to include ICU library in Qt project in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, qt, icu

I need to include International Components for Unicode library in Qt Creator, here is my .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
CONFIG += icu

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Where from can I download this library ? 
I already did

```
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
```

What should I add in my .pro file to use this include in main.cpp ? :
This code gives me an error:

```
#include <unicode/unistr.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        UnicodeString ucs;

Error: undefined reference to `icu_55::StringPiece::StringPiece(char const*)'
```

Answer (score 1):

In normal case you can use icu after "dev" package installed. But in that case icu will not integrated into Qt. Just separated libraries.

You can try rebuild Qt libraries. 
When run *./configure* 
Add appropriate flags to that command:

1. *-icu ................. Enable ICU support [auto]*
2. *-webengine-icu ....... Select used ICU libraries [system/qt] (Linux only)*

Think after your installation of *libicu-dev*, that flags will automatically turn on. Just check *./configure* output.